# Getting Error:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnMetadata.isStatic()Z

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

Getting following error when using spark-cassandra connector in java:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnMetadata.isStatic()Z
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchRegularColumns$1.apply(Schema.scala:95)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchRegularColumns$1.apply(Schema.scala:94)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
```

Comment: What is `Z` in `isStatic()Z` of your error's 1st line doing?

Answer (score 0):

Means you build file is wrong. You have probably pulled in the wrong version of the driver.